# How can I make my dropdown menu work correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement an navigation bar with dropdown menus but its not working, might be some CSS code?
Check it out please.

**I will place here the  HTML code:**

```css
    /*---------------------NAVBAR-------------------*/
    li {
        display: block;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
       }
       
       li:hover {
         cursor: pointer;
       }
       
       ul li ul {
         visibility: hidden;
         opacity: 0;
         position: absolute;
         transition: all 0.5s ease;
         margin-top: 1rem;
         left: 0;
         display: none;
       }
       
       ul li:hover > ul,
       ul li ul:hover {
         visibility: visible;
         opacity: 1;
         display: block;
       }
       
       ul li ul li {
         clear: both;
         width: 100%;
       }
    /*---------------------NAVBAR-------------------*/
```

```html
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

What may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Flexbox to handle the display of your parent and children items. See my code snippet for an example.

```css
.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 11.25rem;
  margin: var(--spacing-10px) 0 0;
  padding: var(--spacing-16px) var(--spacing-16px) 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```